# One click subscription purchase with no shopping cart?

Tags: shopping-cart

I'm looking to do something fairly specific but I'm not entirely sure it's possible with out a huge amount of effort. Basically, after a user has created an account they can add or remove subscriptions (reoccurring profiles) from their account with out having to go through the checkout experience. Think one click shopping on amazon but, but with no shopping cart.

Users can manage subscriptions via their dashboard (remove, suspend) but we would like to skip the whole shopping cart experience to add new subscriptions to their account.

Is this asking too much of Magento?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done but you will have to code it yourself.
You can use the product object as a base for subscriptions and create a link/form to associate a product with a customer with a custom database.

It is not the most complex thing I have heard, but you will have to code it and made the architecture yourself.

Comment: Subscriptions are already supported, so that part works just fine. It's more of bypassing the shopping cart workflow to associate the product to the customer. It sounds like it shouldn't be too difficult for a software developer.